# i can't connect using the api credentials from docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a problem to send a envelope PDF. I'm following the documentation and populating the fields but when I use the send envelope show this error:
An unexpected error occurred.
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 401 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."}'
Please contact system administrator.
Before to start a test I made the authorization access but don't works.
Someone know if that is a change because of OAuth2.0 in the Private Key?
Or I'm connecting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide much information about how you obtained your access token.

However, my guess is that you have an access token "hardcoded" and keep trying to use it in your code.

The access token expires after 8 hours. What you need to do is obtain it in real-time using your code. You can do that with JWT, after you obtained consent once, you can just get another token each time you run your code.

Comment: Yes is it the support of Docusign ask to make this step and works:

you can refer to this documentation on JWT authentication that may be clearer on how to get a JWT token working in your application:

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

The next step after granting consent is to build your JWT assertion (Step 2). After that you can obtain your access token (Step 3) to use in your API call header.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using one of the SDKs to do this? it's a lot easier. You can use C#, Node.js, Java, Python, Ruby and PHP